# URL Rewrite -.htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Simple URL Rewriting for removing .php extensions from the links
I am using the following code on the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

After uploading the site on the hosting server the above mod_rewrite code lead the pages to the following links as I needed...

```
domain.com/abc/index
domain.com/abc/about
domain.com/abc/services
domain.com/abc/rates
domain.com/abc/contact#main
```

but showing **(404 Page Not Found ERROR)** for these pages i.e Not showing the exact pages like index.php, about.php, services.php, rates.php and contact.php#main.... etc

Can anybody please let me know what I am missing? As the Menu links on the web pages like

`<ul class="nav"> 
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li> 
<li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li> 
<li><a href="rates.php">Rates</a></li> 
<li><a href="contact.php#main">Contact Us</a></li> 
</ul>`

Should I have to do something with these menu links too?

Comment: .htaccess is locating on the document root of the website directory and Yes! page not showing... as the physical path of the page on the MENU LINKS is correct.

Comment: The directories and files order on the hosting server is like `public_html/.htaccess,public_html/index.php,public_html/about.php,public_html/services.php,public_html/rates.php,public_html/contact.php,public_html/css/,public_html/js/,public_html/images/`

Comment: Yes! when I access the page 'http://yourdomain.com/about.php' via click on the menu link of the index page... it send me to 'http://yourdomain.com/about' but its shows me nothing and 404 error message display.

Comment: No nothing else on `.htaccess file` Plus I have tried on different browsers but still showing `404 PAGE NOT FOUND ERROR`... Dont know what I am missing?

Comment: I have changed the RewriteBase and RewriteRule. Plus recheck the physical location of .htaccess file on gta folder.. All Done.. but still the same error... :(... you can see also.

Comment: Yes! I forgot!.. actually `all the files and folder including .htaccess file` is on the right location ie on `gta folder`...

Comment: I have re-checked... that is why I am wondering why the pages are not showing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `.php` files from:

```
public_html/*.php
```

To:

```
public_html/gta/*.php
```

What happens is that you're accessing:

```
http://domain.com/gta/about
```

And it tries to find the `.php` file at:

```
http://domain.com/gta/about.php
```

But from what you told me the files are on the previous folder so it's only right it will give you a 404 error.

Given that all files are on the folder `gta` you `.htaccess` can be what you exactly have, but needs to be on the `public_html` folder **and there should be NO `.htaccess` inside the `gta` folder**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your all efforts and time! Prix

Comment: Its all DONE... Thanks GOD..:)

Comment: @marafa glad to know its all working now ;) by the way the site doesn't work well on 1920x1080 :P

Comment: Ohh! I see!.. I will fix this too.. Thanks! anyway