# .htaccess rewrite rule not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using **htaccess** for generating clean urls in my project.

Like, I want to convert this url :

```
https://localhost/erp/profile.php?username=kopyo
```

to this url:

```
https://localhost/erp/profile/kopyo
```

My htaccess code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /erp

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Code I am using is this line but not working
RewriteRule profile/(.*) profile.php?username=$1

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong in this. Thanks

Comment: Does it give `HTTP 1.1 500 Internal Server Error`? Or redirect is wrong? Or...

Comment: Please refer below link you will get your answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929925/url-rewrite-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use proper flags after `RewriteRule` and re-arrange your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /erp/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]    

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^profile/(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It is still not working and when I add a trailing hash (/) to url, everything gets messed up. Css, images won't load at all.

Comment: css/js is a different problem and that just means rules are working fine. For css/js/image etc  you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: No. I am still not able to access this `https://localhost/erp/profile/kopyo`. Still not found error.

Comment: Is css/js files are in `/erp/` then use: `<base href="/erp/" />`